# Google Plus authentication with Oauth2.0(C#) in console application for insert moment

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, oauth

Google Plus authentication with Oauth2.0(C#) in console application for insert moment.
I have created console application for insert moment. but I struck with authentication(Oauth2.0) process.I am following this post "https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert" for insert Moment. Please help me.

```
IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { TasksService.Scopes.Tasks.GetStringValue() });

var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
FullClientCredentials credentials = new FullClientCredentials();
credentials.ApiKey = "<redacted>";
credentials.ClientId = "<redacted>";
credentials.ClientSecret = "<redacted>";
provider.ClientIdentifier = credentials.ClientId;
provider.ClientSecret = credentials.ClientSecret;
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
var state = new AuthorizationState(scopes);
state.Callback = new Uri("http://localhost:15709");
```

Comment: Could you share some code? What does work and what doesn't?

Comment: I have updated my code,Please check

Comment: You shouldn't post your credentials online like this...

Comment: Sorry Maheu, could you please help for this issue.